# Помогите с расшифровкой!

Tags: header, base64, imap, mime

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема с расшифровкой письма IMAP.Вроде бы все подключил и т.д. Все показывает но не в той кодировке.

`=?koi8-r?B?5cLB1Ngg1NkgzM/I?=>`                  (Нецензурное слово)

Знаю что это Base64

`рЙЪДЕГ РТПУФП`               (Нецензурное слово)

А что вот это?

И как их расшифровать?Пробовал imap_base64,iconv,imap_mime_header_decode.Не помогло

Это PHP

Comment: Это текст в кодировке KOI8-R, прочитанный как cp1251. https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это *MIME Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text* (*MIME Часть третья: Расширения заголовка для не-ASCII-текста*), описано в [rfc2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt).

к примеру, на *perl*-е (рас|за)шифровать можно функциями `decode`/`encode` из пакета [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html):

```
use Encode;
$plain = decode ("MIME-Header", $encoded);
$encoded = encode ("MIME-Header", $plain);
```

---

**обновление**

в виде «однострочника». кодируем:

```
$ perl -e 'use utf8;use Encode;print encode("MIME-Header","строка");'
=?UTF-8?B?0YHRgtGA0L7QutCw?=
```

и декодируем (опция `-CO` требуется для «разрешения» вывода *wide characters*):

```
$ perl -CO -e 'use utf8;use Encode;print decode("MIME-Header","=?UTF-8?B?0YHRgtGA0L7QutCw?=");'
строка
```

Answer (score 3):

На C#:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Attachment attachment = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("", "=?koi8-r?XXXXXXX");
            Console.WriteLine(attachment.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

в строке лишняя `>` в конце. и нецензурное слово в результате. Не расшифровывайте, результат принесет вам лишь огорчения.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DI6YTm

Comment: *в строке лишняя `>` в конце* — разве лишняя? это же просто часть сообщения, только не закодированная согласно rfc2047.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin лишняя в смысле что в том смысле, что родные функции расшифровки в C# и, похоже, php (imap_mime_header_decode) не ожидают ее и фейлятся. насчет php, впрочем, не уверен.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, это неправильное поведение, ведь приведённая строка вполне корректна. в perl-е работает правильно (см. мой ответ).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin лишняя - в том смысле, что она не является частью base64/encoded word. а не в том, что ее не должно там быть.

Comment: *результат принесёт вам лишь огорчения* – кстати, возможно и не принесёт: ведь закодированное предложение начинается, как положено, с большой буквы.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `iconv_mime_decode()`

```
iconv_mime_decode($text, ICONV_MIME_DECODE_CONTINUE_ON_ERROR, 'UTF-8');
```

или `mb_convert_encoding()`:

```
function mimeToUtf8($text){
  $result='';
  $text = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
  foreach($text as $fragment){
    if(strtolower($fragment->charset)=='default')
      $fragment->charset='ASCII';
    $result .= mb_convert_encoding($fragment->text, 'UTF-8', $fragment->charset);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: При попытке расшифровки через `iconv_mime_decode` , `mimeToUtf8($text)` выводит это `Р•Р±Р°С‚СЊ С‚С‹ Р»РѕС…`

Comment: это как я понимаю Windows-1251?

Comment: @Ersultan, это результат неправильного преобразования. строку в кодировке *utf8* трактовали как строку в кодировке *cp1251*, а потом перекодировали полученное в *utf8*. вот так можно воспроизвести этот эффект: `echo 'абв' | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8`, результатом будет `Р°Р±РІ` (в локали *utf8*).

Comment: @alexander barakin,а как правильно написать?Чтобы сразу с этой кодировки переводилась в UTF-8?

Comment: @Ersultan, в php? не знаю. может, автор ответа что-то напутал с указанием параметров функций. посмотрите документацию к использованным функциям. вообще правильная реализация rfc2047, конечно, не должна требовать явного указания кодировки при декодировании. поищите функцию с корректной реализацю rfc2047 или, в крайнем случае, воспользуйтесь *perl*-ом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433183/178576

Comment: @Ersultan, ну вообще в *nix   (sh и т.п.): `echo  5cLB1Ngg1NkgzM== | base64 -d | iconv -f koi8-r -t utf8` (base64 текст надо бы дополнять `=` до кратной 4-м длины), а в ПХП сами поищите эквивалент.

Comment: @Ersultan, я дополнил свой ответ примерами-«однострочниками» для удобства использования.